# Spring Security 5 OpenId Resource server Websecurity dsl

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, openid-connect, spring-oauth2

I'm trying to write a spring boot app with following needs

1. open registration endpoint
   1.a. I want that the user be redirected to the the login gateway if authentication fails
2. secured api with openid and oauth provider
   2.a. I also want to validate additional claims when my resource server is call like the "audience"

I'm also a bit unsure of what the dsl is doing in this case...do I need multiple dls?

So far I was able to get the oauth authrization server setup but am not able to get either the 1.a and 2.a working. My security config is below with the dependencies included...

Also I'm using spring security 5.2.X with boot 2.2.X

build.gradle

```
other dependencies before
...
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server')
...
other dependencies after
```

WebSecurityConfig.java

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${auth.issuer-uri}")
    String authIssuerUri;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .csrf().disable()//enable later
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED).and()
            .authorizeRequests(
                ar -> ar
                    .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);
    }


    // this should be used on authorization 
    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        //tried to replicate what spring does by default by adding one more JwtAudienceValidator
        List<OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt>> validators = new ArrayList<>();
        validators.add(new JwtTimestampValidator());
        validators.add(new JwtIssuerValidator(authIssuerUri));
        validators.add(new JwtAudienceValidator());

        NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = (NimbusJwtDecoder) JwtDecoders.fromIssuerLocation(authIssuerUri);
        jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(validators));

        return jwtDecoder;
    }


}
```

application.properties

```java
auth.issuer-uri= from system props

spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=${auth.issuer-uri}

#spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.okta.issuer-uri= ${auth.issuer-uri} tried this also adding relevant spring gradle deps
```